# trying to count vowels, consonants and spaces but ignoring other char's

Tags: java

Here is my code, it works fine ( I think) but if I want to enter in a sentence with some other characters such as ". , * : ; "...etc then surely they would be counted as consonants.

Is there a way to shorten this without typing out all the characters that aren't vowels?

Also, I know I could use "ignoreCase()" instead of typing out all the capital versions of the vowels but realised after I typed them and am too stubborn to change :D

```
public void compute() {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u' || str.charAt(i) == 'A'
                || str.charAt(i) == 'E' || str.charAt(i) == 'I' || str.charAt(i) == 'O' || str.charAt(i) == 'U') {
            vowels++;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            spaces++;
        } else {
            cons++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Character.isLetter` method to check whether character is a valid letter or some special character. Here is what [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) says for isLetter method:

> **public static boolean isLetter(char ch)**
>
> Determines if the specified character is a letter. A character is
>   considered to be a letter if its general category type, provided by
>   Character.getType(ch), is any of the following:
>
> - UPPERCASE_LETTER
> - LOWERCASE_LETTER
> - TITLECASE_LETTER
> - MODIFIER_LETTER
> - OTHER_LETTER
>
> Not all letters have case. Many characters are letters but are neither
>   uppercase nor lowercase nor titlecase.

Comment: which would look like..if(str.charAt(i).Character.isLetter == true) ?? I've never used that method that would be my first guess though

Comment: @Adam No it should be: Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))

Comment: didn't know that, will do

Answer (score 0):

The obvious alternative would be something like this:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
```

and then:

```
if (vowels.contains(str.substring(i,i+1)){
    vowels++;
}
```

You could do sets of course, but what's the point?